Fixed windowing not producing synchronous output
I am using the Apache Beam Python SDK to create a Dataflow pipeline.
Steps:

ingest synchronous pubsub messages
window into 1 second windows with 600ms allowed latency and a 2 second processing trigger
transform data
write to Firestore synchronously (1Hz)

Currently the output is as synchronous as I can get it to be but it is not precise and often I encounter delays.
| "Fixed Window"
>> beam.WindowInto(
    window.FixedWindows(1),
    trigger=AfterProcessingTime(2),
    accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
    # if message late by 600ms, still accept
    allowed_lateness=window.Duration(seconds=0.6)
)

What would be the recommended way to do this?

Hi @Joe Moore, You can check the following documentation and the stack question. These might be helpful.

@NithishKumarRamisetty that's my previous question from a long time ago.

Generally Dataflow is optimized for high throughput and completeness over near-real-time synchronous output.

Forgive me, but what is your point?
